# Salvar dados do DateTime em variável

Tags: angular, ionic

Bom dia, estou finalizando um aplicativo de Alarme onde o usuário seleciona o horário que a Notificação deve aparecer, estou usando o componente nativo do Ionic, o ion-Datetime. Porém não encontro em nenhum lugar de como eu passo os dados que o usuário selecionou em uma variável. A parte das notificações já tenho resolvida com o `this.hora, this.minuto` dentro do trigger.

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
            title: 'Atenção',
            text: '',
            data: { mydata: 'Notificação' },
            trigger:{ every: { hour: this.hora , minute: this.minuto}, count: 1 },
            foreground: true
```

O problema é passar a hora e o minuto do componente Picker pra essas variáveis.

No html está assim:

```
 <ion-datetime [displayFormat]="HH:mm"></ion-datetime>
```

Qual seria uma maneira de passar hora e minuto pra dentro dessas variáveis?

Comment: O que vc quer é pegar os valores do datetime é isso?

Comment: Isso, pegar os valores da hora e do minuto (nesse meu caso)

Comment: O que RZP significa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode pegar o valor do **`datetime`** através de um **[(ngModel)]** por exemplo, aí você terá o valor do tipo **string** no formato que o datetime produz, que seria assim: `10:00`, então vc teria que separar a string para pegar o valor da **`hora (10)`** e dos **`minutos (00)`**, com um método [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) por exemplo. A partir daí os valores da variáveis dentro do **trigger** já estaram corretos:

**TS**

```
tempo: string;
hora: string;
minuto: string;

Tempo() {
   this.hora = this.tempo.slice(0,2);
   this.minuto = this.tempo.slice(3,5);
}

this.localNotifications.schedule({
   title: 'Atenção',
   text: '',
   data: { mydata: 'Notificação' },
   trigger:{ every: { hour: this.hora , minute: this.minuto}, count: 1 },
   foreground: true
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="tempo" (ngModelChange)="Tempo()">
</ion-datetime>
```

**Pode ver um exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-datetime1?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)**.

Comment: Perfeito, muito bom! Uma outra coisa, ao invés de passar hora e minuto como string, consigo transformar para `number`? O LocalNotifications só aceita number pra hora e minuto

Comment: Sim claro, é só utilizar o método Javascript **`Number()`**, ficando assim: `Number(this.hora)` e `Number(this.minuto)`.

Comment: Uma outra pergunta, o que contém nas variáveis `this.hora` e `this.minuto` ? O Logcat me da um erro que eu não posso converter eles em números. `cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer...at...localnotification.LocalNotification.schedule`

Comment: Ou teria alguma maneira de transformar em número(integer) antes de passar as variáveis dentro do Schedule do LocalNotification?

Comment: Estranho, se fez Number(...) já era pra funcionar, pode converter em Number em outra variável e colocar esta variável já convertida no trigger se quiser, tem tbm o método **parseInt()**, mas, a Number já é pra funcionar.